# Unable to run Rails 4 server because of missing sqlit3/Unable to install sqlite3-1.3.10 on Windows 8

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, ruby-on-rails-4.2

Hi I am very new to Ruby and Ruby on rails as well as Windows 8 (I am an OS X user). This is my first attempt of installing it.

I’m running OS Windows 8 and installed Ruby 2.2.3x64 using the rubyinstaller-2.2.3-x64  the Dev Kit DevKit-mingw64-64-4.7.2-20130224-1432-sfx. 
I managed to install ruby & rails.

Executing  version commands I get:

“ruby –version” shows ruby 2.2.3p173 (2015-08-18 revision 51636) [x64-mingw32]
and

“rails –version” shows Rails 4.2.4

I successfully created a new Rails application using command: 
`rails new myapp` 
but after cd myapp I tried to startup the rails server with command
`ruby bin/rails s`
I get the following error messages:

> C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in
>   'require': cannot load such file -- sqlite3/sqlite3_native (LoadError)
>
> from
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:6:in
>   'rescue in ' from
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10-x64-mingw32/lib/sqlite3.rb:2:in
>   '' from
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in
>   'require' from
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:76:in
>   'block (2 levels) in require' from
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in
>   'each' from
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:72:in
>   'block in require' from
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/r
>   from
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler/runtime.rb:61:in
>   'require' from
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/bundler-1.10.6/lib/bundler.rb:134:in
>   'require' from C:/Users/fsamand/myapp/config/application.rb:7:in '' from
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in
>   'require' from
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:78:in
>   'block in server' from
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in
>   'tap' from
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in
>   'server' from
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in
>   'run_command!' from
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.4/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in
>   '' from  bin/rails:4:in 'require' from bin/rails:4:in
>   ''

I checked the first directory
`C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.10-x64-mingw32/lib/`

There is no `sqlite3.rb`

There are subdirectories `…/2.0/sqlite3_native.so` and `…/2.1/sqlite3_native.so`
So, I tried installing sqlite3 by entering:
`gem install sqlite3 --platform=ruby`
and this is what I get:

> Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit... Building native
>   extensions.  This could take a while... ERROR:  Error installing
>   sqlite3:
>           ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>       C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/ruby.exe -r ./siteconf20151007-1508-1v1b7ue.rb extconf.rb checking for sqlite3.h... no sqlite3.h is missing. Install
>   SQLite3 from http://www.sqlite.org/ first.
>   *** extconf.rb failed *** Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check
>   the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may need configuration
>   options.
>
> Provided configuration options:
>           --with-opt-dir
>           --without-opt-dir
>           --with-opt-include
>           --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
>           --with-opt-lib
>           --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
>           --with-make-prog
>           --without-make-prog
>           --srcdir=.
>           --curdir
>           --ruby=C:/Ruby22-x64/bin/$(RUBY_BASE_NAME)
>           --with-sqlite3-dir
>           --without-sqlite3-dir
>           --with-sqlite3-include
>           --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
>           --with-sqlite3-lib
>           --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/lib
>
> extconf failed, exit code 1
>
> Gem files will remain installed in
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/sqlite 3-1.3.10 for inspection.
>   Results logged to
>   C:/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/extensions/x64-mingw32/2.2.0
>   /sqlite3-1.3.10/gem_make.out

I'm stumped.  My question is how do I install `sqlite3-1.3.10` on Windows 8?
I apologize for the formatting I am also new in this forum...

Comment: Skip the agony and use Vagrantbox or something similar to run a *nix virtual machine from windows.

Comment: You're going to have a lot better luck with OS X on this. Seriously. Or Linux. Rails development on Windows is **horrible** at the moment, involving a lot of fiddling with download/local/extract locations of library sources.

Comment: Ok thanks.  I will consider switching to Linux.